# How do I make apps in my optional package run using the virtualized file system/registry of the main package?

Tags: windows, installation, msix

I've created a "related set" (in the language of MSIX) consisting of a main package and an optional package. Each of these two packages contains standalone applications. When I run the applications that are part of the optional package, I find that they run within their own virtualized file system, separate from the virtualized file system of the main package.

Using the "Invoke-CommandInDesktopPackage" Powershell command, I find that the applications in the optional package should be able to "see" the contents of the virtualized filesystem of the main package, as virtualized (by browsing to the relevant folder under C:\Program Files\WindowsApps); but they seem to also have their own VFS.

Can I force them to run in **the same VFS as the main package's apps use**, so that they will have the same view of the filesystem and the same view of the Registry?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415147).

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft they should be running in the same container. Here is an extract from "[Optional packages and related set authoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/optional-packages)" article:

> Optional packages and related sets all run inside the main app's MSIX container.

I haven't built an optional package recently but I will give it a try when I have the chance. It might be a bug in what OS which breaks this shared container (Microsoft had a similar similar bug when modification packages were released).

What Windows version are you testing on?

Comment: I am no longer actively pursuing an answer to this question, as design decisions changed to the point where this arrangement of packages is no longer necessary for us. The machines used to try this functionality out were all Windows 10 machines, but I couldn't now tell you what specific version of Windows 10. A discussion of this issue is taking place at the following Microsoft-affiliated discussion board: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/msix/combining-optional-packages-and-modification-packages/m-p/3418963